# Array.push not working in forEach loop using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Hi I am new to node js and I am trying to make an array from an object

```js
data.forEach((title) => {
  let array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    array.push(title.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title.title.slice(1))
  }
  console.log(array);

  //access.forEach((conf)=>{
  // conf.title
  // array
  //})
})
```

```html
<script>
  let data = [{
      title: "user",
      fields: "required",
      access: "done"
    },
    {
      title: "root",
      fields: "default",
      access: "done"
    },
    {
      title: "super Admin",
      fields: "allready access",
      access: "defualt"
    },
    {
      title: "user1",
      fields: "required",
      access: "done"
    },
    {
      title: "test user",
      fields: "required",
      access: "done"
    },
  ]
</script>
```

As I want an array which contain all the title in it so I can use that array field inside the access.forEach method but what am getting is title but not in same array but as a different output

expected output

```
array = [User,Root,Super Admin,User1,Test user]
```

Comment: an arrow function you pass into `forEach` executes for every item in the array and you create a new array `let array=[]` for every item of your original one. You either want to declare the array ousite of the function or just use `map`

Comment: @BhaveshSingh I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using simple [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**Working Demo :**

```js
let data = [{
  title: "user",
  fields: "required",
  access: "done"
}, {
  title: "root",
  fields: "default",
  access: "done"
}, {
  title: "super Admin",
  fields: "allready access",
  access: "defualt"
}, {
  title: "user1",
  fields: "required",
  access: "done"
}, {
  title: "test user",
  fields: "required",
  access: "done"
}];

const array = data.map((obj) => obj.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + obj.title.slice(1));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function you pass into `forEach` is executed for every item in the `data` array so that you create a new array `let array=[]` for every item of your original one. You either want to declare the array outside of the function:

```
let array=[];
data.forEach(item => {
   array.push(item.title[0].toUpperCase() + item.title.slice(1));
})
```

or even better use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let titles = data.map(item => item.title[0].toUpperCase() + item.title.slice(1))
```

An output in both cases will be:
`["User", "Root", "Super Admin", "User1", "Test user"]`